# Visually editing code or open a program on test start

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm pretty new to Coded UI Tests and after searching through documentation , I've failed to find a solution to this.

Is it possible to visually ( Like when I recorded the test ) edit the code/steps after it has been generated, or, introduce new steps ?

Is there a way to set the Test to open `Internet Explorer` with a specific URL as the Test begins ? ( Different from Windows Key + Clicking on the icon in the menu bar )

[image: Coded UI Test Actions]

Comment: Please only ask one thing at a time. I suggest you move the second topic (about opening a URL) into a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the [UI Map Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269469(v=vs.140).aspx) of Coded UI. From there you can make many changes to the recorded tests.

To record new steps and new assertions to go into an existing Coded UI test do the following. In the [TestMethod] in the ".cs" file put the cursor where the calls to the new code should be placed, I like to add a blank line at that place to make it precisely clear to me where the new item is added. Use the context (right click) menu and select "Generate code for Coded UI test" => "Use Coded UI test builder". Then use the record and generate tools just as when the test was first recorded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, AdrianHHH ! I've fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the steps from the UI Map Editor and added this line to the [TestMethod].cs file

```
 [TestInitialize()]
        public void BrowserStarter()
        {
            BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
        }
```